# Find $\sup \{x: x^2 + x< 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, supremum-and-infimum

> Find $\sup \{x: x^2 + x< 1\}$

If I factor, I get $x(x+1) < 1$. Should I use first derivative and find critical points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$^1$ $$x^{2}+x<1\Leftrightarrow \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}<x<\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2},$$
we have

$$\sup \{x: x^2 + x< 1\}=\sup\, ]\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}[\ =\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

The last equality follows from the definition of the [supremum  of a set of real numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremum).

--

$^1$ In general, if  $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and the discriminant $\Delta =b^2-4ac>0$, then $f(x)$ has two real roots $x_1,x_2$ and $f(\alpha)=a(\alpha -x_1)(\alpha -x_2)$. If $a>0$, then $f(\alpha)<0$ for $\alpha\in ]x_1,x_2[$.  If $a<0$, then $f(\alpha)>0$ for $\alpha\in ]x_1,x_2[$.

Comment: so supremum is (-1 + root(5))/ 2, thanks.

Comment: Yes, @maria. You are welcome.

Comment: @maria: do you understand the equivalence $x^{2}+x<1\Leftrightarrow \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}<x<\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$?

Comment: yes, when you plot the parabola x^2 + x -1, that interval is below x-axis

Comment: @maria That's a possible interpretation. In general, if  $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and the discriminant $\Delta =b^2-4ac>0$, then $f(x)$ has two real roots $x_1,x_2$ and $f(\alpha)=a(\alpha -x_1)(\alpha -x_2)$. If $a>0$, then $f(\alpha)<0$ for $\alpha\in ]x_1,x_2[$.  If $a<0$, then $f(\alpha)>0$ for $\alpha\in ]x_1,x_2[$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the region where $x^2+x<1$ and the region where $x^2+x>1$ are separated by points where $x^2+x=1$.  What are those points?

Comment: those pts are (1/2)* (root(5)-1) and (1/2)*(-1 - root(5)). Now what?

Comment: @maria: From that, you should be able to show that $$\{x:x^2+x<1\}=\left(\frac{-1-\sqrt5}2,\frac{-1+\sqrt5}2\right).$$ What is the supremum of the set, then?

Comment: its the right end pt thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Complete the square. Just write $x^2+x = (x+\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4}$. So you are trying to find $$\sup \{x: (x+\frac{1}{2})^2 < \frac{5}{4}\}$$